# Extract data from PostgreSQL DB without using pg_dump

Tags: python, sql, xml, postgresql

There is a PostgreSQL database on which I only have limited access (e.g, I can't use pg_dump). I am trying to create a local "mirror" by exporting *certain* tables from the database. I do not have the permissions needed to just dump a table as SQL from within psql. Right now, I just have a Python script that iterates through my table_names, selects all fields and then exports them as a CSV:

```
for table_name, file_name in zip(table_names, file_names):
    cmd = """echo "\\\copy (select * from %s)" to stdout WITH CSV HEADER | psql -d remote_db | gzip > ./%s/%s.gz"""%(table_name,dir_name,file_name)
    os.system(cmd)
```

I would like to not use CSV if possible, as I lose the field types and the encoding can get messed up. First best would probably be some way of getting the generating SQL code for the table using \copy. Next best would be XML, ideally with some way of preserving the field types. If that doesn't work, I think the final option might be two queries---one to get the field data types, the other to get the actual data.

Any thoughts or advice would be greatly appreciated - thanks!

Comment: How do you connect to database? ODBC, JDBC (Jython), Pygres, psycopg?

Comment: How's that you can't use pg_dump? What kind of permissions you think you have to have so you can use pg_dump?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It puzzles me the bit about *"I do not have the permissions needed to just dump a table as SQL from within psql."* `pg_dump` runs standalone, outside `psql` (both are clients) and if you have permission to connect to the database and select a table, I'd guess you'd also be able to dump it using `pg_dump -t <table>`. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 2):

If you use `psycopg2` you can use `cursor.description` to check column names, and use fetched data type to convert it to required string like data to acceptable format.

This code creates `INSERT` statements that you can use not only with PostgreSQL, but also with other databases (then you probably will have to change date format):

```
cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM %s" % (table_name))
column_names = []
columns_descr = cursor.description
for c in columns_descr:
    column_names.append(c[0])
insert_prefix = 'insert into %s (%s) values ' % (table_name, ', '.join(column_names))
rows = cursor.fetchall()
for row in rows:
    row_data = []
    for rd in row:
        if rd is None:
            row_data.append('NULL')
        elif isinstance(rd, datetime.datetime):
            row_data.append("'%s'" % (rd.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S') ))
        else:
            row_data.append(repr(rd))
    print('%s (%s);' % (insert_prefix, ', '.join(row_data)))
```

In psycopg2 there is even support for `COPY`. Look at: COPY-related methods on [their docs](http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/cursor.html)

If you prefer using metadata then you can use my recipe: [Dump PostgreSQL db schema to text](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/576557-dump-postgresql-db-schema-to-text/?in=user-186902). It is based on [Extracting META information from PostgreSQL](http://www.alberton.info/postgresql_meta_info.html) by Lorenzo Alberton

Answer (score 1):

You could use these queries (gotten by using "psql --echo-hidden" and "\d ") to get the base metadata:

```
-- GET OID
SET oid FROM pg_class WHERE relname = <YOUR_TABLE_NAME>

-- GET METADATA
SELECT a.attname,
  pg_catalog.format_type(a.atttypid, a.atttypmod),
  (SELECT substring(pg_catalog.pg_get_expr(d.adbin, d.adrelid) for 128)
   FROM pg_catalog.pg_attrdef d
   WHERE d.adrelid = a.attrelid AND d.adnum = a.attnum AND a.atthasdef),
   a.attnotnull, a.attnum
FROM pg_catalog.pg_attribute a
WHERE a.attrelid = <YOUR_TABLES_OID_FROM_PG_CLASS> AND a.attnum > 0 AND NOT a.attisdropped
ORDER BY a.attnum;
```

This gives you the name, data type, default, null flag and field order within the row.  To get the actual data, your best bet is still CSV--the built in COPY table TO STDOUT WITH CSV HEADER is very robust.  But if you are worried about encoding, be sure to get the value of server_encoding and client_encoding just before dumping the CSV data.  That combined with the metadata from the above query should give enough information to properly interpret a CSV dump.