# Postgresql Database Backup Using Python

Tags: python, postgresql

I would like to backup database using Python code. I want to backup some tables of related data. How to backup and how to choose desired tables using "SELECT" statement?

e.g.

I want to get data from 2014-05-01 to 2014-05-10 of some tables and output this result as .sql extension file

How can I get this format using python code?
If you don't mind, please explain.
Thanks.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use psycopg2 to establish the data connection. There are quite a few examples in the documentation:

http://initd.org/psycopg/

Once you have your data source configured, iterate through the results of your "SELECT" statement building a `INSERT INTO` statement by printing the result set to a file. Basically some reverse logic.

That way, if the time comes and you need to use your backup file, you simply run the SQL file which inserts the data back in...

Example:

```py
import psycopg2
import sys


con = None

try:

    con = psycopg2.connect(database='local', user='local', password='local',port='1970')
    cur = con.cursor()
    cur.execute('SELECT x FROM t')
    f = open('test.sql', 'w')
    for row in cur:
        f.write("insert into t values (" + str(row) + ");")
except psycopg2.DatabaseError, e:
    print 'Error %s' % e
    sys.exit(1)
finally:
    if con:
        con.close()
```

Then to restore:

```bash
psql <dbname> <username> < test.sql
```

Comment: The advice to write "insert into" statements are meant for writing that code into a text file, not called from PsycoPG. I was a little confused by the answer at the beginning. You should do something like http://stackoverflow.com/a/2771803/582906

Comment: I don't think you understand. Once you've fetched the data from a table using a SELECT, you can do anything with that data. What I am saying is that you can reverse the SELECT into an INSERT, it's quite simple.

Also if you read the question again, he's wanting a logical subset of data backed up, not a physical as such.

You could accomplish this using pg_dump -t <table name> etc and just create a backup table with the subset of data he is asking of.

Comment: Sure, I understand and my answer provide since the beginning the idea to use custom queries instead of pg_dump. I was only saying that the first version of your answer may lead some confusion (as well as mine, maybe) and now I believe that both have improved thanks to some code.

Comment: @d1ll1nger for types like date, str(row) prints `datetime.date(...)`

Comment: @muser try `f"insert into t values {tuple(map(str, row))};"`

Answer (score 4):

If your OS is Linux, you can use the code below.
First, you should run `apt-get install postgresql`.

```
def create_essentials():
    yaml_file = open("settings.yaml", 'r')
    settings = yaml.load(yaml_file)
    db_name = settings["db_name"]
    db_user = settings["db_user"]
    db_password = settings["db_password"]
    db_host = settings["db_host"]
    db_port = settings["db_port"]
    backup_path = settings["backup_path"]
    filename = settings["filename"]
    filename = filename + "-" + time.strftime("%Y%m%d") + ".backup"
    command_str = str(db_host)+" -p "+str(db_port)+" -d "+db_name+" -U "+db_user
    return command_str, backup_path, filename


def backup_database(table_names=None):
    command_str,backup_path,filename = create_essentials()
    command_str = "pg_dump -h "+command_str

    if table_names is not None:
        for x in table_names:
            command_str = command_str +" -t "+x

    command_str = command_str + " -F c -b -v -f '"+backup_path+"/"+filename+"'"
    try:
        os.system(command_str)
        print "Backup completed"
    except Exception as e:
        print "!!Problem occured!!"
        print e

def restore_database(table_names=None):
    command_str,backup_path,filename = create_essentials()
    command_str = "pg_restore -h "+command_str

    if table_names is not None:
        for x in table_names:
            command_str = command_str +" -t "+x

    command_str = command_str + " -v '"+backup_path+"/"+filename+"'"
    
    try:
        os.system(command_str)
        print "Restore completed"
    except Exception as e:
        print "!!Problem occured!!"
        print e
```

Answer (score 1):

The first idea that comes to my mind is to dump your tables calling [pg_dump](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/app-pgdump.html) command, similar to the approach presented [here](http://codepoets.co.uk/2011/postgresql-backup-script-python/) (but google is plenty of alternatives).

However, since your backup strategy requires you to select precise dates and not only tables, you will probably have to rely on a sequence of queries, and then my advise is to use a library like [Psycopg](http://initd.org/psycopg/).

**EDIT**:

I cannot provide a complete example since I don't know:

- which tables do you want to dump
- what is the precise backup strategy for each table (i.e. the SELECT statement)
- how you want to restore them. By deleting the table and then re-creating it, by overwriting db rows basing on an ID attribute, ...

the following example generates a file that stores the result of a single query.

```
import psycopg

conn = psycopg2.connect("dbname=test user=postgres")  # change this according to your RDBMS configuration
cursor = conn.cursor()

table_name='YOUR_TABLE_HERE'  # place your table name here
with open("table_dump.sql") as f:
    cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM %s" % (table_name))  # change the query according to your needs
    column_names = []
    columns_descr = cursor.description
    for c in columns_descr:
        column_names.append(c[0])
    insert_prefix = 'INSERT INTO %s (%s) VALUES ' % (table_name, ', '.join(column_names))
    rows = cursor.fetchall()
    for row in rows:
    row_data = []
        for rd in row:
            if rd is None:
                row_data.append('NULL')
            elif isinstance(rd, datetime.datetime):
                row_data.append("'%s'" % (rd.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S') ))
            else:
                row_data.append(repr(rd))
    f.write('%s (%s);\n' % (insert_prefix, ', '.join(row_data)))  # this is the text that will be put in the SQL file. You can change it if you wish.
```

Comment: How to get my result by using Psycopg library. If I use this library, I get sample 'SELECT' query result... but I really want .sql file just like export file of phpmyadmin.. later.. I'll reuse this .sql file for restore by import file. That's why... I don't know how to write this code by python language... If u don't mind, please give some sample code for this. Thanks.

Comment: @sharipha, Can I dump database using psycopg2?

Answer (score 0):

1. first export the password of postgres using below command
   os.environ["PGPASSWORD"]='{}'.format(database_password)
   Note: database_password is variable to which i have assigned a password
   value
2. change the working dir path to \bin folder
   os.chdir(r'C:/Program Files/PostgreSQL/15/bin')
3. create dump command
   command = 'pgdump -h {0} -U {1} -p 5432 -d{2}'.format(host,user,dbname)
4. call subprocess.Popen
   p=subprocess.Popen(command,shell=True)
5. issue wait command till process complete
   p.wait()

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Could you edit your answer a little by formatting your code using backticks (`\``)?