# How to remote access PostgreSQL database and get its dump to local?

Tags: python, django, database, postgresql

I need to access the remote database server(linux) and also take its dump to my local(mac).

```
DATABASES = {
'default': {
    'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
    'NAME': 'test-name',
    'USER': 'test-user',
    'PASSWORD': 'pwd',
    'HOST': 'test.amazonaws.com',
    }
}
```

Comment: This may come in handy: http://stackoverflow.com/a/37674134/3886053

Answer (score 0):

In local bash, you can connect and dump the remote database with `pg_dump` command, see [Copying PostgreSQL database to another server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1237725/copying-postgresql-database-to-another-server)

Using Python is similar, except that you need to use `psycopg2` module to connect and send commands to database server. You may find this post useful [Postgresql Database Backup Using Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23732900/postgresql-database-backup-using-python)

Alternatively, if you need to execute the script in the database server, a better idea would be dump it remotely, then fetch it to local machine.